# Complete solution to $A\vec{x}/|\vec{x}|_1=\vec{b}$

Tags: linear-algebra

This is my first post here and I haven't done a serious math problem in a few years so I hope this all makes sense.

I'm working with a 7x11 matrix and want to find solutions to an equation of the form $A*\vec{x}/|\vec{x}|_1=\vec{b}$.

I've found the complete solution to $A*\vec{x}=\vec{b}$ where the null space of $A$ spans an $\mathbb{R^4}$ subspace in $\mathbb{R^{11}}$.

Let $\vec{x_0}$ be a particular solution to the equation $A*\vec{x}=\vec{b}$.
Let $\vec{n}$ be an arbitrary vector in the null space $N$ of $A$.
Let $\vec{x} \epsilon X \iff \vec{x} = \vec{x_0}+\vec{n} $ for any $ \vec{n} \epsilon N$

So I've reformulated my problem to this: find the subspace $S$ of $X$ such that $\vec{s} \epsilon S \iff \vec{s}/|\vec{s}|_1\epsilon X$

I've gotten as far as to say that $\vec{s}=\vec{x_0}*|\vec{s}|_1+\vec{n}$ ( so not very far). What's my next step? Is this the correct direction? Any properties of $|\centerdot|_1$ that could be useful?

I'm thinking that because I'm simply translating $N$ by $\vec{x_0}$ to define $X$, it may not even be possible to scale $\vec{x_0}$ by ${|\vec{s}|_1}$ and then add only an arbitrary $\vec{n}$ in order to "re-enter" $X$, so to speak.

Comment: Not an expert in numerics but one thing you could try is to rephrase as a constrained minimisation problem, since there are known algorithms for that. I.e., instead of solving 
$$ A\frac{x}{|x|_1} = b$$
you can solve 
$$ \min_y |Ay-b|^2 \text{ subject to } |y|_1 = 1$$
Looks like Lagrange multipliers setup